# is nice() used to change the thread priority or the process priority?

Tags: linux, pthreads, scheduler, nice

The man page for `nice` says "nice() adds inc to the nice value for the **calling process**. So, can we use it to change the nice  value for a thread created by `pthread_create`?

EDIT:
It seems that we can set the nice value per thread.

I wrote an application, setting different nice values for different threads, and observed that the "nicer" thread has been scheduled with lower priority. Checking the output, I found that the string "high priority ................" gets outputted more frequently.

```
void * thread_function1(void *arg)
{
  const pid_t tid = syscall(SYS_gettid);

  int ret = setpriority(PRIO_PROCESS, tid, -10);
  printf("tid of high priority thread %d , %d\n", tid ,getpriority(PRIO_PROCESS, tid));
  while(1)
  {
    printf("high priority ................\n");
  }
}


void * thread_function(void *arg)
{
  const pid_t tid = syscall(SYS_gettid);
  int ret = setpriority(PRIO_PROCESS, tid, 10);
  printf("tid of low priority thread %d , %d \n", tid ,getpriority(PRIO_PROCESS, tid));
  while(1)
  {
    printf("lower priority\n");
  }
}


int main()
{
  pthread_t id1;
  pthread_t id2;

  pid_t pid = getpid();
  pid_t tid = syscall(SYS_gettid);

  printf("main thread : pid = %d , tid = %d \n" , pid, tid);
  pthread_create(&id1, NULL, thread_function1,  NULL);
  pthread_create(&id2, NULL,thread_function,   NULL);

  pthread_join(id1, NULL);
  pthread_join(id2, NULL);
}
```

Comment: Includes for this code :
`#include<cstdio>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/syscall.h>
#include<sys/resource.h>`

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The [pthreads man page](http://linux.die.net/man/7/pthreads) says:

> POSIX.1 also requires that threads share a range of other attributes
>   (i.e., these attributes are process-wide rather than per-thread):
>
> [...]
>
> - nice value (`setpriority`(2))

So, theoretically, the "niceness" value is global to the process and shared by all threads, and you should not be able to set a specific niceness for one or more individual threads.

However, the very same man page also says:

> **LinuxThreads**
>
> The notable features of this implementation are the following:
>
> [...]
>
> - Threads do not share a common nice value.
>
> **NPTL**
>
> [...]
>
> NPTL still has a few non-conformances with POSIX.1:
>
> - Threads do not share a common nice value.

So it turns out that both threading implementations on Linux (LinuxThreads and NPTL) actually violate POSIX.1, and you can set a specific niceness for one or more individual threads by passing a `tid` to [setpriority()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setpriority) on these systems.

Comment: But why in some JVM implementation, java thread priority has a 1:1 mapping with the nice value?  //www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/priority_what.shtml In addition , i wrote a application ,setting difference nice value for different thread, and observed that the nicer thread has been scheduled with lower priority by checking out how frequently the output is.

Comment: @pierr, interesting, it turns out that both NPTL and Linux threads do violate POSIX.1. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Is it still the same case that the threads on Linux do not share a common nice value?

Comment: @blueskin, Frédéric gives you the answer: look at the man page. It is likely not following POSIX because as far as the OS is concern each thread is a separate task.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the man page for setpriority](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/2-setpriority/), a lower nice value (nice values are in the range of `-20` to `20`) means higher priority in scheduling. It looks like your program works as expected (`nice = -10` gives this thread higher priority).

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to test how changing these values really affects the thread's priority, so I modified your snippet to this benchmark:

- Running on default `SCHED_OTHER` scheduling policy
- Created 12 low priority threads to make sure they **compete on resources** - on Red hat 7 with 8 cores. (`cat /proc/cpuinfo`)
- Modified the `thread_function()` to do some "number crunching work"

When setting to edge priorities you can definitely see with `top -H` that the high priority thread runs more often, but no starvation occurs to other threads. relevant fields are `NI` and `TIME+`

[image: Thread's NICE level and timing view]

From [top man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/top.1.html):

> NI  --  Nice Value
> The nice value of the task.  A negative nice value means
> higher priority, whereas a positive nice value means lower
> priority.  Zero in this field simply means priority will not
> be adjusted in determining a task's dispatch-ability.

> TIME  --  CPU Time
> Total CPU time the task has used since it started.

```
#include<cstdio> 
#include<pthread.h> 
#include<unistd.h> 
#include<sys/syscall.h> 
#include<sys/resource.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define NUM_THREADS 12
 
struct ThreadParams{
 const char* priority;
 const int niceLevel;
};

void * thread_function(void *arg)
{
  const pid_t tid = syscall(SYS_gettid);


  struct ThreadParams* params = (ThreadParams*)arg; 

  int ret = setpriority(PRIO_PROCESS, tid, params->niceLevel);
  printf("tid of %s priority thread %d , %d\n", params->priority, tid ,getpriority(PRIO_PROCESS, tid));
  long long int count = 0;
  while(1)
  {
      count++;
      if(count == 10000000000) //10^10 iterations
      {
          printf("%s priority ................\n", params->priority);
          count = 0;
      }
  }
}



int main()
{
  pthread_t tIdHigh;
  pthread_t tIdsLow[NUM_THREADS];

  pid_t pid = getpid();
  pid_t tid = syscall(SYS_gettid);

  printf("main thread : pid = %d , tid = %d \n" , pid, tid);
  
  struct ThreadParams highParams = {"High", -20};
  struct ThreadParams lowParams  = {"Low", 19};

  for(int i=0; i < NUM_THREADS ; i++)
  {
    pthread_create(&(tIdsLow[i]), NULL,thread_function,  &lowParams);
  }
  
  pthread_create(&tIdHigh, NULL, thread_function,  &highParams);
  
  for(int i=0; i < NUM_THREADS ; i++)
  {
    pthread_join(tIdsLow[i], NULL);
  }
  pthread_join(tIdHigh, NULL);
  return 0;

}
```

Compiled with  `g++ <FILE_NAME>.cpp -lpthread`.

Run `top -H -p $(pidof <PROCESS_NAME>)` to enable *Threads-mode* and get information for specific process