# Does "nice" affect the priority of Java threads

Tags: java, linux, multithreading, thread-priority, nice

On a Unix system, you can run a process at lower CPU "priority" (pedantically, it does not change the thing that is called the `priority`, but rather influences what share of available CPU time is used, which is "priority" in the general sense) using the `nice` command:

```
 nice program
```

And you could use that to run a JVM process:

```
 nice java -jar program.jar
```

The Java program run by that JVM process will start multiple threads.

Does the `nice` change affect the scheduling of those Java threads? That is, will the Java threads have a lower CPU priority when run as

```
 nice java -jar program.jar
```

that when run as

```
 java -jar program.jar
```

In general, this will be system dependent, so I am interested in the Linux case.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2866604/829571

Comment: "Niceness" is not the same thing as priority.  The goal of niceness is that if two processes are CPU-bound at the same time, the "nicer" one should get fewer CPU cycles on average.  "Priority" usually is about which process is able to preempt the other when some asynchronous event occurs.

Comment: To summarise an answer [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7684821/545127): POSIX requires that the threads of a process share a *nice* value, but in Linux the can have different *nice* values that can cause threads to be scheduled more or less often, so implicitly the *nice* value **does** affect the scheduling of threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually...Niceness is a property of the application according to POSIX.1.  Here is a more detailed post. [is nice() used to change the thread priority or the process priority?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7684404/is-nice-used-to-change-the-thread-priority-or-the-process-priority)

Answer (score 2):

According to what `ps` reports niceness is applied to java threads. I ran this quick test with a java application that waits for user input:

Start process with : `nice -n 19 java Main`
Output of `ps -m -l 20746`

```
F S   UID   PID  PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  TTY        TIME CMD
0 -  1000 20746 10006  0   -   - - 1739135 -    pts/2      0:00 java Main
0 S  1000     -     -  0  99  19 -     - futex_ -          0:00 -
1 S  1000     -     -  0  99  19 -     - wait_w -          0:00 -
1 S  1000     -     -  0  99  19 -     - futex_ -          0:00 -
1 S  1000     -     -  0  99  19 -     - futex_ -          0:00 -
```

Start process with : `nice -n 15 java Main`
Output of `ps -m -l 21488`

```
F S   UID   PID  PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  TTY        TIME CMD
0 -  1000 21488 10006  0   -   - - 1722494 -    pts/2      0:00 java Main
0 S  1000     -     -  0  95  15 -     - futex_ -          0:00 -
1 S  1000     -     -  0  95  15 -     - wait_w -          0:00 -
1 S  1000     -     -  0  95  15 -     - futex_ -          0:00 -
1 S  1000     -     -  0  95  15 -     - futex_ -          0:00 -
```

The `NI` column seems to reflect what I passed to `nice` and the priority changes accordingly too. I got the process ID (20746, 21488) using `jps`.

Note that running `jstack 21488` for example will not give the above information.

I ran the above on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (64bit)

Answer (score 0):

Java is not special. It's just a process, and the OS sets its "niceness" the same way as with any other process.

On Linux, Java threads are implemented using native threads, so again, "niceness" is subject to OS controls in the same way as any other native thread.